# Mongoose - How to remove all elements from a unique array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a unique array in my Schema as:

```
requests: {
    type: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user",
        unique: true,
        required: false
      }
    ],
    validate: [memberLimit, "{PATH} overflow"]
  }
```

The memberLimit function:

```
function memberLimit(val) {
  return val.length <= 6;
}
```

To remove all elements from the array, I tried:

```
team.requests = [];
```

It is producing the error:

```
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: heroku_sx6rhpl8.teams.$requests_
1 dup key: { : undefined }
    at Function.MongoError.create (H:\Projects\xyz\node_modules\mongoose\node_
modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:45:10)
    at toError (H:\Projects\xyz\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib
\utils.js:149:22)
    at H:\Projects\xyz\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collecti
on.js:1035:39
    at H:\Projects\xyz\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\con
nection\pool.js:541:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: heroku_sx6rhpl8.teams.$requests_1
dup key: { : undefined }',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: heroku_sx6rhpl8.teams.$requests_1 d
up key: { : undefined }' }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try to confirm that typeOf `teams.requests`  is an array. If thats true then try clearing all your indexes in your Database and re-run your code. Hope that helps.